# " D/OpenGLRenderer: DecorView @4fea9e4 is drawn by HWUI ". repeats in Android Studio log

Tags: android, android-studio, android-log, hwui

" D/OpenGLRenderer: DecorView @4fea9e4 is drawn by HWUI ".
The above line keeps repeating in Android Studio log. I have selected the app name and show only selected application option. I have googled for it, but found no references to such a log. Can anyone please tell what this log is about and what should be done to eliminate/hide these. I have attached the screenshot link [android log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1klrG.png). Please help me.

Comment: since You are testing on phone you need to set  enable OpenGL traces  none...I think in your phone this is set to logcat....check if this is the case...??

Comment: @PN10 Thanks for the suggestion. But "Enable OpenGL traces" option is already set to "none" in my device. I think, I have never accessed that option.

Comment: well  if that isn't  the case can you please update ur question with ur xml files ...log files also , full logcat from starting ?

Comment: This actually isn't  an error i think well let me have a more closer look  to know ??Is your output is coming as expected or not?

Comment: Ok. I will update the question. And I am getting expected output.